# Placing other elements below the two div elements which were placed side-by-side

Tags: css, html

the code i have tried is 
CSS Code

```
#tools
{
    float:left;
}
#sketch 
{
    border: 10px solid grey;
    float:left;
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="tools">
    <p>These are my tools</p>
</div>
<div id="sketch">
    <p>This is my sketch</p>
</div>
<button type="button">Click</button>
```

I am placing the two divs side-by-side
the button is geting displyed side to the divs 
but I want the button below the div

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/FB3BL/)

Answer (score 1):

Clear the float:

```
button { clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add wrapper with a clearfix:

```
<div class="wrapper cf">
<div id="tools">
<p>These are my tools</p>
</div>
<div id="sketch">
<p>This is my sketch</p>
</div>
</div>
<button type="button" >Click</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brutusmaximus/5KmK6/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "clear: left;" for the button to cancel the "float: left" of the previous div element.

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the two :

1) button { 
          clear : both;
   }

2) Add a class clearfix to the Div - "sketch" that adds a pseudo element to the DOM after it to clear the float added.

```
  <div id="sketch" class="clearfix">
          <p>This is my sketch</p>
   </div>
  .clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
   }
```